# Write bash output to file while using here document

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, redhat

I'm writing a bash script to grab an archive (specifically, the gcc-4.9.1 source) from ftp.gnu.org, which it does using a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents). I'd also like to direct ftp's output to a log file, in order to make the script's output cleaner while keeping any information that might be needed. I'd also like to use bash's double-bar to run an error-catching function that prints some output and exits if ftp returns unsuccessfully.

```
#get the archive
echo "getting the archive from ftp://${HOST}/${FTPPATH}${ARCHIVE}"
/usr/bin/ftp -inv $HOST > ${VERNAME}_logs/ftp.log || errorcatcher "failed to connect to ftp server, check ${VERNAME}_logs/ftp.log" <<FTPSCRIPT 
user anonymous
cd $FTPPATH
binary
get $ARCHIVE
FTPSCRIPT
```

The problem is, this hangs, and ftp.log looks like this:

```
Trying 208.118.235.20...
Connected to ftp.gnu.org (208.118.235.20).
220 GNU FTP server ready.
ftp>
ftp>
ftp>
```

The commands are clearly not getting passed to the ftp client, and I imagine either the output redirection or the double pipes are causing this, as without them both the script successfully gets the archive.

Is there any syntax that allows me to pass interactive commands to ftp while still allowing output redirection and conditional execution following the return?

Comment: is this going to be a permanent ftp? If so why not mount the FTP? Once that has been done you can use it as a normal FS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are feeding the wrong command with the here document.

```
/usr/bin/ftp [ ...args... ] || errorcatcher [...] <<FTPSCRIPT
```

should be

```
/usr/bin/ftp [ ...args... ] <<FTPSCRIPT || errorcatcher [...]
```

The contents of the here document do not begin until the line following the `<<`. You could even write

```
/usr/bin/ftp -inv $HOST > ${VERNAME}_logs/ftp.log <<FTPSCRIPT || 
user anonymous
cd $FTPPATH
binary
get $ARCHIVE
FTPSCRIPT
  errorcatcher "failed to connect to ftp server, check ${VERNAME}_logs/ftp.log"
```

if you find that more readable (I'm not sure that I do, but it's an option), or also

```
/usr/bin/ftp -inv $HOST > ${VERNAME}_logs/ftp.log <<FTPSCRIPT \
  || errorcatcher "failed to connect to ftp server, check ${VERNAME}_logs/ftp.log"
user anonymous
cd $FTPPATH
binary
get $ARCHIVE
FTPSCRIPT
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, and I appreciate the explanation of here document syntax (the bash reference could be clearer). Thanks!